# Akka Typed Actors and AKka Http - cannot find ActorRefFactory

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to work with typed actors version 2.6.3 and akka http version 10.1.11
while all worked fine in non typed actors , now I am getting compilation error

```
object Main extends App {

   def createServer(implicit system: ActorSystem[IdentityCalculated]) = {

implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

 }
 def apply(): Behavior[IdentityCalculated] = {
Behaviors.setup { context =>

  val identityManager = context.spawn(IdentityManager(), "identity-manager")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  implicit val scheduler = context.system.scheduler

  identityManager.tell(CalculateIdentity(context.self))

  Behaviors.receiveMessage{
    case IdentityCalculated(_,_,_) =>
      println("got response")
      Behaviors.same
  }
}

}
ActorSystem(Main(), "credentials-manager")

}
```

what am I missing?
I want to create http server when I get the message that the identity was calculated how ever i am getting compilation error in the materializer 
creation

> Main.scala:19:50: implicit ActorRefFactory required: if outside of an Actor you need an implicit ActorSystem, inside of an actor this should be the implicit ActorContext
>   [error]     implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
>   [error]                                                  ^
>   [error] one error found

thanks

Comment: If you hit a compilation error and want help about, indicating/pasting the trace is required.

Comment: added the exact error

Answer (score 1):

You can use classic streams (which are typed, despite running on an untyped `ActorSystem`) by replacing:

```
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

with

```
implicit val materializer = system.classicSystem
```

Answer (score 1):

In Akka 2.6 the ActorMaterializer API has been deprecated and a new system wide materializer that is always available have been introduced. To run a stream you should only need the implicit `ActorSystem[T]` in scope.

`akka-stream-typed` is only needed if you want to use the specific stream operators for interacting with Akka typed actors (`ActorSource`, `ActorFlow` and `ActorSink`)

However the Akka HTTP APIs is still depending on the classic APIs so you may need to adapt them to be able to bind a HTTP endpoint for example.

If that is your issue, you can see how to do that in the Akka HTTP quickstart guide here: https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-http-quickstart-scala/http-server.html

Comment: This example was helpful - worth noting is that `toClassic` is now `classicSystem` (from the linked example).

Answer (score 0):

I had to use akka-stream-typed and not akka-stream